# Using frontdoor JSP to login to experience cloud site

Tags: authentication, experience-cloud, frontdoor.jsp

Is the login for experience cloud sites no more supported using frontdoor.jsp? As per this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386254&type=1), it should be.

For some quick testing, as given [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_frontdoorjsp.htm&type=5), I'm using the form element sample inside a simple HTML page. I've extracted the session ID from SOAP login response made via SOAP UI tool and embedded the same in my html. And the URL used is in the format `https://<my-domain-name>.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp`. It works for standard salesforce site, but not for community sites anymore. I'm always get redirected to the community login page instead.

I came across an article that suggested that the URL to be used for community sites should be in the format: `https://<my-domain-name>.my.site.com/<any-community-suffix-url>/secur/frontdoor.jsp`. I've tried this too but doesn't work.

Comment: From the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_frontdoorjsp.htm&type=5):  _Not all session types are supported with frontdoor.jsp, such as Experience Cloud site API sessions. For these sessions, consider using SAML for single sign-on, instead.
You have several ways to get a Session ID, such as from UserInfo.getSessionId() in Apex, $Api.SessionID and other sources. Sometimes the ID values from these sources vary depending on context, don't work with frontdoor.jsp, and can pose security risks as you use them. Use the access_token from an OAuth authentication instead_

Comment: I've seen this. Won't be able to use `UserInfo.getSessionId()` & `$Api.SessionID` because I'm trying to load the experience site inside a 3rd party mobile app (which uses Salesforce Mobile SDK). However, while trying out this feature on the mobile app, I've used the `access_token` obtained from OAuth authentication. But the same behavior was observed. Just to ensure that this works in a normal web page load firstly, I've tried this on a simple HTML page using the token from SOAP API `login` call. I believe the SOAP call gives the same session ID or equivalent as OAuth.

Comment: Ref to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm), `Session contexts are based on the domain of the request. That is, the session context changes whenever you cross a hostname boundary, such as from .salesforce.com to .vf.force.com or .lightning.force.com.`. If I make a SOAP API `login` call, I believe the response should be giving me the session token from `.salesforce.com`

Comment: `.my.site.com` is an Enhanced Domain site. What's the outcome of your test in an org without Enhanced Domain? How about the same test with and without Enhanced Domain in Winter '22 org

Comment: The outcome remains same for sites with as well as without enhanced domain. Also, checked playing around by hardcoding access token/ session ID from REST API end point as well as SOAP end points. Always getting redirected to the community login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the login for experience cloud sites no more supported using frontdoor.jsp?

No, it is still supported. All I needed was to get the session token from the community domain/ login. As mentioned in my comment (ref: [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm)), `Session contexts are based on the domain of the request`. So, the session or access token for the community site (*`my.site.com` domain - for orgs with enhanced domain*) will be different than the ones fetched via `SOAP login`, `UserInfo.getSessionId()` or `$Api.SessionID`. In my case, I was able to get this via OAuth, since my actual requirement was to get this token in a mobile app.

**Access tokens received from a domain can be used to login to a page within or served from that particular domain only using *frontdoor.jsp***. The URL to be prefixed to `secur/frontdoor.jsp` can be actual instance URL and it need not be domain specific URL.

**Additional Info**: On the `Setup` > `Session Management` page, the details of community site specific token can be observed (of type *ChatterNetwork*).